# Overlay not appearing on map

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am trying to add a polygon overlay on to an MKMapKit map. The Map appears - but the polygon does not... Am I missing something obvious?

Code attached:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = NO;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCoords[4] = { {43,-100}, {43,-80}, {25,-80}, {25,-100} };
    MKPolygon *worldOverlay = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:worldCoords count:4];

    [self.mapView addOverlay:worldOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
}
```

And the Renderer class...

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if (![overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon *)overlay;
    MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:polygon];
    renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    return renderer;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks
Guy

Comment: Is the map view's delegate set/connected?

Comment: After the addOverlay call, put `NSLog(@"mapView=%@, overlay count = %d", self.mapView, self.mapView.overlays.count);` and see what it says.  Also put an NSLog or breakpoint in the rendererForOverlay method to see if it's getting called.  Question says "and the Renderer class...".  Does that mean the rendererForOverlay method is not in the same class as the viewDidLoad or did you mean "and the Renderer method"?

Comment: Thanks Anna - overlay count = 0 :(

Comment: ... I have put a breakpoint in and the "addOverlay" method is being called. And yes sorry - I mean the rendererForOverlay method.

Comment: Interestingly, the NSLog that you have stated above says "mapView=(null)"....

Comment: That means the mapView outlet is not connected.  If you are using xib/storyboard, connect the mapView outlet and the map view's delegate outlet.  Since mapView is null, the addOverlay call does nothing.

Comment: I have that working now - output as follows. Still no overlay :(

Comment: 2013-12-19 14:12:58.838 iPadMap[1510:60b] self.mapView=<MKMapView: 0x146517f20; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x178222740>>, overlay count = 1

Comment: 1) Make sure you are viewing the area where the overlay is expected (eastern half of US).  2) Put an NSLog or breakpoint in the **_rendererForOverlay delegate method_** to make sure it's getting called.  3) You're testing with iOS 7 simulator or device, right?  Because prior to iOS 7, the delegate method was "viewForOverlay".

Answer (score -3):

I have stumbled across the answer!

After Anna's help in the comments above helped me to get the layer working - it seemed that you must initiate the mapView **after** adding the layer. so after

```
[self.mapView addOverlay:worldOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
```

you need

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. If you reinitialize the mapView it won't be connected to overlay you had added. However this won't matter if the mapView you're reinitializing is not the one connected to the actual view. I suggest you try commenting out your second line and you'll find that it works just fine, either that or they are not being called in the order you think they are.

Comment: Hmm - you are right. Commenting the initWithFrame line still works. Yet if I move that line above the addOverlay line - it does not. I am confused now!

Comment: If you reintialize the mapView you've made a new one that isn't the one on screen, therefore you're adding the overlay to a mapview you don't see. If you add the overlay to the one connected to the screen and then make a new one and point the "mapview" variable at that one, it won't remove the overlays you added to the first one. This is the crux of memory leaks. If you did the `initWithFrame` line multiple times you'd have made loads of MKMapViews, but only one would be connected to mapView the variable

Comment: Basically rather than modifying the contents of memory where mapView is pointing to, that `initWithFrame` changes where in memory mapView is pointing. If you do that before adding overlays, you'll be adding overlays to somewhere that the onscreen MKMapView is not connected to. If you add overlays first then mapView is still pointing to the onscreen one and you'll see the overlays, after than you can point mapView anywhere you want since you've already done the changes to the onscreen MKMapView. I hope that makes sense, I am not a teacher by trade :-)

Comment: That makes perfect sense - I need to go back to programming school by the looks of it as memory pointers should be bread and butter! Thanks for your help.